# Displaying streaming twitter on webpage with socket.io/node.js

Tags: html, node.js, twitter, socket.io

I'm trying to build a Twitter streaming web application using node.js socket.io and twit.

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  ,Twit = require('twit')
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var watchList = ['love', 'hate'];


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Connected');

  var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         ''
  , consumer_secret:      ''
  , access_token:         ''
  , access_token_secret:  ''
})
 T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: watchList },function (stream) {

  stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {

        io.sockets.emit('stream',tweet.text);
        console.log(tweet.text);

  });
 });
});
```

Here's my client side

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
      socket.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
    $(
        '<div class="tweet">' + tweet.text + '</div>');
        }); 

  });

  </script>
</div>
```

When I run node app.js and try to connect to localhost:8080 I just get a blank page, even if everything ( soket.io, jquery, ... ) seems to have loaded correctly.

Here's a sample of the server output :

```
info  - socket.io started
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized pwH0dbx4WvBhzSQXihpu
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/pwH0dbx4WvBhzSQXihpu
debug - set heartbeat interval for client pwH0dbx4WvBhzSQXihpu
debug - client authorized for
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"stream","args":["RT @mintycreative: Great to chat       today RT @SharonHolistic: Treatments available tomorrow http://t.co/5Poq3KU08u Book yours now #WestMidsHou…"]}
```

debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"stream","args":["RT @laurenpeikoff: #BREAKING @ScottsdalePD confirms - police are investigating Michael Beasley for alleged sexual assault. @12News @azcentr…"]}

Hope you can help me to correct my mistakes.

Comment: do you have the console output handy?

Comment: shouldn't `io.sockets.emit` be only `socket.emit`?

Comment: io.sockets.emit sends to all.

Comment: When I add io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){ before the stream function I loose the console log output

Comment: In fact, it's waiting for me to access localhost:8080 to log the tweets. I just want to put those tweets into a webpage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved

Here's the code without any mistakes : (server side)

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  ,Twit = require('twit')
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var watchList = ['love', 'hate'];
 var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         ''
  , consumer_secret:      ''
  , access_token:         ''
  , access_token_secret:  ''
})

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Connected');


 var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: watchList })

  stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {

    io.sockets.emit('stream',tweet.text);


  });
 });
});
```

(client-side)

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('stream', function(tweet){
        $('#tweetd').append(tweet+'<br>');
        });
  </script>
  <div id="tweetd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the code, for those copying and pasting this, the server side script has an extra `});` at the end of the file that is not needed.

Comment: @maximeHeckel, nice example you have shared. I had also tried same thing for one on my app. but I need some user instead of "keywords". means you have mentioned some keywords (eg watchList), but I want tweets from my friends. I have userid for the same too. but I am not getting result as expected. Here I have raised question. please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965221/how-to-get-tweets-from-the-users-in-node-js Do you have any idea what I am missing? or you have any example to get live tweet from selected screen_name of the tweeter? Thanks

Comment: How are you solving problems when twitter stream hangs - no new "heartbeat" events for a long time

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are constructing a new twitter listener each time a socket connection is opened. You should move that outside of the `connection` event. This is likely not ideal. I'm not sure how the twitter module is handling that internally but it likely actually is creating a new connection to their API each time a websocket connects.

On the client side you jQuery could bit a bit different. If you just wanted to add a tweet to the page each time a tweet occurs, append a new tweet to the body element with `$('body').append()`

See [this gist for reference.](https://gist.github.com/TJkrusinski/5536583)