# Twitter Track Api display on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
var request = twitter_oauth.post(
"https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter",
access_token,
access_token_secret
```

Hi i have made a successful track that in the command line shows all the latest tweets using the word Twitter. I am trying to get this to appear on a html webpage instead of command line can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this post is what you are looking for in order to have your Twitter script results appear on a web page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439818/5884189