# How to get tweets from the users in node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am making a small application build on node.js, which needs real time tweets from the users twitter account. I have used for that "Twit" ( node.js library, look at [this](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)  ) and write following code at server side.

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         '...',
  consumer_secret:      '...',
  access_token:         '...',
  access_token_secret:  '...',
  timeout_ms:           60*1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
});

var userids = '100001,100002,100003';
T.stream('statuses/filter', 
    {
        follow: userids,
        stall_warnings: true
    },
    function(stream) {
        stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
            console.log(tweet);
        });
    }
);
```

I have to use *stream* because I need real time tweets of the users (100001,100002 and 100003). I have seen many example, shows me same code. But in my case it is not working. If I pass single userid (e.g. 100001), it works sometime, sometime not. Don't know what is the problem with this code. Can anybody help me solve it out.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a probability that the users your application 'follows' aren't tweeting at the time you are running it. Have you tried running your app and monitoring the users on twitter.com and see if it they are actually active?

Comment: @dodev, I have create on dummy account and check tweeting on it, while my app is running.